# How to have a policy class implement a virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates, oop, policy

I'm trying to design a policy-based class, where a certain interface is implemented by the policy itself, so the class derives from the policy, which itself is a template (I got this kind of thinking from Alexandrescu's book):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestInterface {
public:
  virtual void test() = 0;
};

class TestImpl1 {
public:
  void test() {std::cerr << "Impl1" << std::endl;}
};

template<class TestPolicy>
class Foo : public TestInterface, TestPolicy {

};
```

Then, in the `main()` function, I call `test()` on (potentially) various different objects that all implement the same interface:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<TestInterface*> foos;
  foos.push_back(new Foo<TestImpl1>());
  foos[0]->test();
  delete foos[0];
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile, though, because

```
the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Foo<TestImpl1>’:
  virtual void TestInterface::test()
```

I thought `TestInterface::test()` is implemented because we derive from `TestImpl1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this to work the policy class needs to inherit from the interface class:

```
class TestInterface {
public:
  virtual void test() = 0;
};

template< class Interface >
class TestImpl1 : public Interface {
public:
  void test() {std::cerr << "Impl1" << std::endl;}
};

template<class TestPolicy>
class Foo : public TestPolicy<TestInterface> {
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a boost::mpl approach:

keeping your TestInterface and TestImpl as they are:

```
#include <boost/mpl/inherit.hpp>

using namespace  boost::mpl;

template <class TestPolicy>
class Foo: public inherit2< TestPolicy, inherit2< TestInterface , empty_base >::type >::type
{
...
}
```

should work